# postfix disable blacklist checking for registered user

Tags: postfix, blacklist

Many users has dynamic IP and sufficient number of these IP is blacklisted. How to disable check Postfix blacklist only for registered user? I want only block incoming mail from blacklisted IPS only.

I have added **permit_sasl_authenticated** to smtpd_helo_restrictions. Now it looks like this

```
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit
```

However, I am not yet tested it.

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no

smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/sasl/mail_support.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/sasl/mail_support.key
smtpd_tls_CAfile=/etc/postfix/sasl/mail_support.pem

smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no

unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 450
maximal_queue_lifetime = 7d
minimal_backoff_time = 1000s
maximal_backoff_time = 8000s
smtp_helo_timeout = 60s
smtpd_recipient_limit = 16
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 12


smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, **permit_sasl_authenticated**, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit
smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023, permit
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_relay_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023, permit

smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
disable_vrfy_command = yes

myhostname = mail
myorigin = /etc/hostname
mydestination =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
mynetworks_style = host

virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_domainaliases_maps.cf
virtual_uid_maps = static:150
virtual_gid_maps = static:8
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_domainaliases_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf

virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1

content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024

header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
enable_original_recipient = no

milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891, inet:localhost:8893
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891, inet:localhost:8893
```

Comment: What does your current config look like, what did you try, what did you expect to happen, what happened instead?

Comment: add permit_sasl_authenticated to smtpd_client_restrictions

Answer (score 1):

Adding `permit_sasl_authenticated` to `smtpd_client_restrictions` before `reject_rbl_content` will do tricks. It will terminate access checking if user has authenticated via SASL, so no further checks (`reject_rbl_client`)  applied.

<sub>converted from comment-by-Reinaldo-Gil Oct 23 at 18:59</sub>